# Custom UITableViewCell change when selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nib, custom-cell

My custom `UITableViewCell DayOfWeekTableViewCell` is displaying some odd behavior [as you can see here.](http://gfycat.com/BelovedImpressiveCowrie)

I tried to fix it by adding the following lines to my `DayOfWeekTableViewCell` class

```
class DayOfWeekTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeek: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmountSpent: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        //Added these lines
        let colorView = UIView()
        colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView  = colorView
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

But now my app behaves like [this](http://www.gfycat.com/SpecificUnlinedBlesbok). I just want the cell to look the same when I select it, not be covered up by some rectangular blob.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` will solve your problem. I don't know what it will look like on swift, so just post it in objective c. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I used that in my TableViewController method cellForIndexPath and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the behaviour where a cell is not changed when selected, you can add following method in your `DayOfWeekTableViewCell` class. It just make sure that selection style of every cell is `.None`

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.selectionStyle = .None
}
```